# How can I get two anchor tags positioned on the upper-left and upper-right of my page, in a div that covers the page, and ouside another div?

Tags: html, css

I was going to work with some JSON to fill in content as an exercise, but while putting together my initial HTML I ran into an issue simply trying to have a couple links on either side of the page. I have a main-container div, and inside I have the two links, and another div, which I was going to put the JSON content.

This question has nothing to do with the JSON content to be clear, I just got stuck on the css of trying to position the two  tags right. I've got height: 100% for the html, body, main-container, and second div. The closest I've got is floating the two tags to the left and right, then using an overflow: auto on the main-container, but the problem is that when you shrink the page, the a tags overflow the descendant div, and also, regardless of the size, there is a weird bar at the bottom of the page, with a scrollbar.

Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/g8qeko98/

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Checkboxes from JSON</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main-container">
    <a id="home" href="#">Home</a>
    <a id="details" href="#">Details</a>
    <div class="checkboxes">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are my styles:

```
html, body {
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #7FA1E5;
}
#main-container {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
a {
    background: darkslategray;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: calibri;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 2%;
}
#home {
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: lightblue;
    float: left;
}
#details {
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: lightblue;
    float: right;
}
.checkboxes {
    background: #A3B7E5;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 5%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need that height of `90%` on `html` and `body`. I don't see any weird bars on bottom but my guess is you're referring to the result of setting that height.

Second, you just need to set your values a little more carefully to prevent items from overlapping.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #7FA1E5;
}

#main-container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

a {
  background: darkslategray;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: calibri;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px 5%;
}

#home {
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: lightblue;
  float: left;
}

#details {
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: lightblue;
  float: right;
}

.checkboxes {
  background: #A3B7E5;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 60px 5%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <a id="home" href="#">Home</a>
  <a id="details" href="#">Details</a>
  <div class="checkboxes">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eqpbkozr/

Comment: Okay thanks. I was trying to get the .checkbox div to extend the whole page. You used 100vh on the main-container and that did all the work? Also, how do I get rid of the vertical scrollbar then?

Comment: I guess you could use something like `min-height: 80%;` instead of height on `#checkboxes`.